# Turn off Mail animations OS 10.8.3

Tags: email, animation

I have tried using this code in the terminal to turn off the reply animation in Mail

defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations -bool true

It doesn't work for me. I turn off Mail, enter the above in terminal, press return, turn on mail. Same hideous distracting reply animation.

I have also checked at the application Tinker Tools--but there is no turn off Mail animation there that I can find.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *animation*?

Comment: Hi Robuust--yes, I guess that would help! I mean what is called in the code Reply animation. When I Reply to an email the reply window jumps forward and flies into the center of the window. It's annoying to have to watch it every time. I successfully disable the same irritant connected with Send email, but having trouble with this one. Thanks for helping.